# Rails Validations. Gym/Client/Membership

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

So I'm a little stumped on a validation.

```
A client has many gyms and has many memberships
A gym has many clients and has many memberships
A membership belongs to a gym and belongs to a client
```

For one of my validations I'd like to set it up as so:

```
Validation: A client can have only one membership with gym
```

My thought so far being, I need to do something like, Membership.all and check if a client_id == self[client_id] or something of that nature. If so then render json: error "client has membership" else Membership.create!(member_params)

I feel like I'm overthinking at the moment and there must be a validates shorthand for such a situation

I'm a little unsure of how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect your models to look like this:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :gyms, through: :memberships
end

class Gym < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :clients, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :gym
end
```

To add the unique validation that one client can only have one membership with a gym at the same time add the following line to `Membership` model:

```
 validates :client_id, uniqueness: { scope: :gym_id }
```

Additionally, I suggest adding a unique index to those columns in the database:

```
add_index :memberships, [:client_id, :gym_id], unique: true
```

Comment: @spikermann does the order in the unique index array matter? (i.e. `[:client_id, :gym_id]` vs `[:gym_id, :client_id]`)

Comment: super helpful thank you.  can you elaborate on the add_index part a little more? Is that just so the database has it's own understanding of that unique connection?

Comment: @BigBoyyo A uniqueness validation is a good first step but it does not guarantee uniqueness in the database which could still happen because of race conditions or database inserts that bypass validations. Only a unique index in the database ensures that this cannot happen. Therefore it is recommended to do both.

Comment: @AbM To ensure uniqueness the order in the index does not matter. When you use the index for lookup too (what is usually the case with foreign keys) then indexes with a higher cardinality are usually preferred because they are more efficient. Therefore I would put the `client_id` to the front because I expect there to be more clients than gyms.

Answer (score 1):

You need uniqueness in the membership class, like this:

```rb
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :membership
  validates :gym_id, uniqueness: {scope: :client_id}
end
```